# Prove that the function is injective

Tags: functional-equations

Prove that this function is injective.
$$f(x + 2xf(y)^2) = yf(x) + f(f(y) + 1)$$

I try to fix $x$ and put two values for $y$: $a$ and $b$, but I can't prove it.

Maybe it is better to fix $y$ and choose two values for $x$?

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate